# Investigate a data structure in Java with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, data-structures

I have an object in java, I know that this object contains useful informations for me, the problem is I don't know the names of the fields, I don't know if this object contains real data or just references, considering this and the fact that I only know the label of this object, what options do I have to debug this data structure and get informations out of it?

It's possible to list every objects corresponding to a particular type?

Comment: You only have the class file?

Comment: no, i have my source code + the libraries that i use with access to the source, so not only the bytecode but also the actual source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print (and search) a field in a class :

```
static Object fieldOdClass(final String className,
        final String valeurRecherche1) {
        try {
            final Field[] f = Class.forName(className).getFields();
            for (int i = f.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                System.out.println(f[i].toString());
                if (f[i].toString().endsWith(valeurRecherche1)) {
                    return f[i].toString();
                }
            }
        } catch (final ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // manage errors;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the source file, and look in the Outline view:

If it's not visible in your perspective, go to: *Window* > *Show View* > *Outline*

That should give you a good overview of what data/methods the object provides.

Comment: what source? my source or the library source?

Comment: If the object you are interested in is of type `SomeDataObject`, then open `SomeDataObject.java`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve the issue is to have this object in debug mode where you can easily discover object fields and their values in the Watch View. But this becomes tricky if you have no option to run in debug. Other way I'd suggest is to override `toString()` method with some generic logic that outputs everything recursively using reflection. You can accomplish the same with no boilerplate code implemented using any of JSon/XML serialization library. The rest is to make it works in the place.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Debug in Eclipse to view all the attributes of the object at runtime. It's very useful and you don't need to create any code. Just put a breakpoint at the line where your object is read. Also, when your application is running on debug mode and the line where your object is read is highlighted, you can press CTRL+SHIFT+I to view detailed information.