# Transform java class instance to primitive types only

Tags: java, transform, converters, primitive-types, flatten

I want to "flatten"/transform an instance from a given Java class to another instance containing primitive types only.

Every field from an object that is not already a primitive type will have to be flattened recursively too, so that the resulting object contains a flattened view of the original one, with primitive types only.

For example, given the following classes:

```
class Element {
  int id_;
  Position position_;
}

class Position {
  int x_;
  int y_;
}
```

The resulting instance would be of type:

```
class FlattenedElement {
  int id_;

  int x_;
  int y_;
}
```

And I would expect such a behaviour:

```
Element e = new Person ( 42, new Position(0, 0) );
FlattenedElement fe = e.flatten();
```

**Is there any tool/library able to do so?**

Or do I need to write my own flattener, using the reflection API I take it?

*-- edit following most comments --*

I changed my example to avoid any confusion with `String` and `byte` (I won't have to deal with Strings).

I need to keep the semantics of the data in the resulting conversion. The output primitive types data will be directly involved in a parallel computation using OpenCL, which only understands primitive data types.

In other words, what I need is to break encapsulation to manipulate directly the primitive data types embedded in the class hierarchy.

Comment: Any reason you do not flatten a string to a `char[]`?

Comment: Yes. I want to use a library called Aparapi that only supports primitive types but `char` ;)

Comment: Write your own flattener using reflection.

Comment: Should be simple enough to do with reflection. But the better question is, why would you ever want something like this? I can't think of a single reason where this makes sense. I think we can be pretty sure that you're trying to solve the wrong problem here.

Comment: Like I said to @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen I'm trying to using a library called Aparapi that only supports primitive data types. And I don't to fully rewrite my app using primitive data types, so an automatic converter would help me a lot.

Comment: What is the purpose of all of this? massive parallel processing?

Comment: This is a very specialized task you are asking for, don't hope for a library. You are in effect serializing your objects, just in a very non-standard way. Perhaps it would be less work to turn everything into a `byte[]` -- that's what serialization does for you.

Comment: This is it @HovercraftFullOfEels! I want to use this feature in a simulation code that will be parallelized using OpenCL on both CPU and GPU.

Comment: I can give it a try @MarkoTopolnik, but I'm not sure I'll be able to deserialize my data correctly because of Aparapi and OpenCL (the tools that require primitive data types).

Comment: I didn't have classic serialization in mind, but something like a `DataOutputStream`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I tested your solution but converting to byte involves losing semantics of the data, and I need to directly pass them to function after the flattening. I updated my question to be hopefully more accurate in the behaviour I expect.

Comment: Ok, say you get a flattened object. How are you going to use it with Aparapi? I'm not an Aparapi expert, but looks like it's aim is processing *arrays* of primitives, will you then "vectorize" arrays of flat-objects?

Comment: So what are your field types, you mentioned wrappers, classes containing primitives and wrappers, what about Date? what about String? what about Collections?

Comment: That's what I intend to do @tair

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh: I don't need neither `Date` nor `String`, but Collections will be translated to their Array equivalent

Comment: Looks like Java is not the best language for the task now, you just can't efficiently operate on primitive arrays/buffers without losing OO semantics. In C++ or like, you can use custom allocators, so that your objects are aligned in memory in a way you tell it

Comment: I even can imagine, how scatter/gathering your objects can be the bottleneck, possibly outweighing the advantage of parallelization

Comment: @tair: this is the bottleneck of any parallelization using an external hardware accelerator! The point is to lower it as much as possible compared to computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but you will need a third party library to create the new class, like Javaassist. To introspect the class to be flattened, you will use reflection as some users already said. Here is another example that I wrote for you:

```
public static Class flatten( Class classToFlatten ) {

    for ( Field f : classToFlatten.getDeclaredFields() ) {

        Class type = f.getType();
        String name = f.getName();
        int modifiersConfig = f.getModifiers();

        // extract all modifiers here (using the isXXX methods of the Modifier class)
        System.out.print( Modifier.isPrivate( modifiersConfig ) ? "private" : "" );
        System.out.print( " " + type );
        System.out.print( " " + name );
        System.out.println();

        if ( type.isPrimitive() ) {
            // primitive type.
            // does not need to be converted.
            // insert in the new class as it is (using Javaassist).
        } else {

            // no primitive type.
            // needs to be converted and tested.
            // insert in the new class after the conversion (using Javaassist).

            // convert rules...
            switch ( type.getSimpleName() ) {

                case "String":
                    // insert in the new class a array of chars.
                    break;

                // cases to test if the field is a wrapper (Integer, Long, etc.).

                // other rules tha you need here...

            }

            // here you need to use recursion...
            // you can use this method, but you will need to create
            // a new parameter, passing the class that is been built
            // to insert new fields in it (relative to the type that is been
            // reflected)

        }
    }

    // return the new class here and outside the method, use the newInstance
    // method to create new instances of this class
    return null;

}
```

With this I think you will be able to do what you need, but I thinking why you need this. You will have some problems when you have arrays of some type that will be recursively flettened, because you will maybe need to "backtrack" to resolve their type or to run the flatten algorithm some times. With generics, inner classes, methods and all kinds of class members you will have the same problem. I'm not sayng that this is impossible, but it will consume a lot of your time and maybe you could solve your problem in a simpler way as some users already said. Well, I hope you can do what you need and I want to know the results if possible! Maybe your solution can be the seed of a new library! Ok, enought of brainstorming :D Here are some links.

[The Javaassist library can be downloaded here.](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/)

[Here you can see a simple tutorial.](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200711/Journal200711.jsp#a4) I suggest that you use it only to begin, because the Javaassist API may have been improved since the creation of the tutorial, so, after reading this, refactor your code (if possible), reading the library docs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from my POV, one way would be this:

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    Atring address;

    public FlattenedPerson flatten() {
        FlattenedPerson fp = new FlattenedPerson(this.name.getBytes(), this.houseNumber, this.address.getStreet.getBytes(), this.address.getTown.getBytes());
        return fp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer but this is not what I expect. I need a dynamic behaviour that will adapt to any class.

Comment: Ah, you might want to edit your question that you are looking for a library/way to do that for any class. (I assume you want to leave primitive types as they were and convert everything else to byte arrays?)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Reflection

Have a look at [the little sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468011/investigate-a-data-structure-in-java-with-eclipse/11468385#11468385), return Field's name.

So to get the value of this Field you have to return `f[i].get(Object)`